# Using Windows Powershell to measure file size. Output is in bytes would like to be able to adjust to kb, mb, ...etc

Tags: powershell, storage

I am attempting to run a powershell cmdlet to measure file size of certain files within a group of folders.  I am able to get the output I want, but when I run it again with the sum in KB I only know how to output one of the criteria at a time in KB.  I would like to have the exact output I have already just in KB.  Here is the script I am running.

```
PS Y:\> (Get-ChildItem -Path Z:\CMP\Chicago\Culligan -Filter "*global*" -
Recurse | Measure-Object -Property length -Maximum -Minimum -Average -Sum)
```

Here is what I am running where I am able to get the output in KB but just   for one of the measurements.

```
PS Y:\> (Get-ChildItem -Path Z:\CMP\Chicago\Culligan -Filter "*global*" -
Recurse | Measure-Object -Property length -Maximum -Minimum -Average  
Sum).sum/1KB
```

Answer (score 0):

You could assign them to a variable and then do each part individually

```
$h = Get-ChildItem -Path Z:\CMP\Chicago\Culligan -Filter "*global*" -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property length -Maximum -Minimum -Average
$h.Average /1KB
$h.Maximum /1KB
$h.Minimum /1KB
```

Answer (score 0):

Try piping to `ForEach-Object {$_.sum / 1KB}`

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692684.aspx

Or use the Select-Object command to do the formatting:

```
Select-Object Name, CreationTime,  @{Name="Kbytes";Expression={$_.Length / 1Kb}}
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx